# Can't send email from visual studio 2013 apache cordova

Tags: cordova, github, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am working on visual studio 2013 apache cordova app . I was worked on VS2015 cordova app , then suddenly it stoped working . I don't know why , but i changed my project to VS2013 with same code which was working before in VS2015 . I 've add the plugin of email from https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer
but when i run my project i always have "service not avialable " . here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here.</div>
    <div class="separator-fields"></div><a class="action-button" id="sendemail">Contact Us</a>


    <script src="js/framework.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {

        cordova.plugins.email;

        }, false);

        $("#sendemail").click(function () {
            cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable(
                function (isAvailable) {
                     alert('Service is not available') ;
                });
                window.plugin.email.open({
                to: ['max.mustermann@appplant.de'],
                cc: ['erika.mustermann@appplant.de'],
                bcc: ['john.doe@appplant.com', 'jane.doe@appplant.com'],
                subject: 'Greetings',
                body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig'
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me .

Comment: It silly to includ 2 versions of jquery. Pick one.

Comment: i delete on of them but it still not working

Comment: Try deleting the other.

Comment: Also, your isavailable function is wrong. On true, you're alerting not available which is the opposite.

Comment: i delete another one but it still not working

Comment: i have followed the code in https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer , and it was working in VS2015 .

Comment: On what platform are you trying this. iOS, Android, else? Do you have an email account setup on that device/emulator?

Comment: on andrid platform , and yes i have email account setup on the device